# How to groupby a column every time its sum reaches a specified amount?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame `df` like this

```
     x
0    8.86
1    1.12
2    0.56
3    5.99
4    3.08
5    4.15
```

I need to perform some sort of `groupby` operation on `x` to aggregate `x` every time its sum reaches 10. If the index of `df` were a `datetime` object, I could use `pd.Grouper` as below

```
grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="min")
grouped["x"].sum()
```

which would group by the datetime index and then sum `x` every minute. In my case I don't have a `datetime` target to use, so `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=10))` yields `ValueError: Invalid frequency: 10`.

The desired output dataframe, after applying `groupby()` and `sum()` operations would look like this

```
     y
0    10.54
1    13.22
```

because elements 0-2 of `df` sum to 10.54 and elements 3-5 sum to 13.22

How can I group `x` by its sum, every time the sum reaches 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
# cumulative sum and modulo 10
s = df.x.cumsum().mod(10)
# if value lower than 10, we've reached the value
m = s.diff().lt(0)
# groupby de cumsum
df.x.groupby(m.cumsum().shift(fill_value=0)).sum()

x
0    10.54
1    13.22
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks yatu, the answer certainly helped! I tried it on some data and it seems to work, but the output is unintuitive (it even looks wrong sometimes). I'll play around with it some more to try and understand

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a for-loop and rolling sums.

```
data_slices = [] # Store each sample
rollingSum = 0
last_t = 0
for t in range(len(df)):
    rollingSum += df['x'][t] # Add the t index value to sum
    if rollingSum >= 10:
        data_slice = df['x'][last_t:t] # Slice of x column that sums over 10
        data_slices.append(data_slice)
        rollingSum = 0 # Reset the sum
        last_t = t # Set this as the start index of next slice

grouped_data = pd.concat(data_slices, axis=0)
```